# Employee has left but and been removed from website but searching for their name still returns website

Tags: google-search-console, html, web-development

An Employee of ours left November last year, and any mention of them has been removed from our website, but when searching their name in Google our site still returns as one of the top results.

We have tried reindexing the entire website 3 times now, but nothing has changed. 
How do we fix this?

Comment: Could you please describe how you have tried to reindex the site exactly? Is your website very large (= consisting of many URLs)? Have a look at Search console as well as your server log files to see when Googlebot has last crawled your site.

Comment: What happens if you click the sites which return as search results? Is a site shown? What is the return code for this site?

Comment: How, or how many pages, did their name appear on your site? A _single_ "list of employees"-type page? Or multiple pages eg. blog author or credit on many pages?

Comment: How long ago have you removed all references to Employee?

Comment: Hi, answering some of the comments here, all references to the employee were removed November last year, he was mainly mentioned in one "Meet the team" employee page, and maybe once or twice as a get in touch contact on some of the others

Answer (score 2):

If you already added your website in Google Webmaster Tools, then you can use [Google Removal tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal) to remove specific URL from search result for temporarily (90 days - it is enough to reindex your website again).

Before you make any request, make sure it shows 400 Error, or 301 redirect to parent directory/Homepage, so next time, when spider crawl your website, it reindex your website based on redirection, **But it's take some time to recrawl and reindex your website again.**

If you think some of URL, you don't want to remove from your website, but not to display in search result, then you can use [Noindex Meta tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en).

Also clear your browser cache, when you test search result again.